# AutoHotkey: Mapping arrows key to PS3 pad buttons?

Tags: button, mapping, autohotkey, playstation3

PS3 D-PAD in Windows generates arrow key output (just like if you pressed UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT on the keyboard) insted of decent POV - which is hopeless.

So I want to map keyboard arrow keys output to PAD buttons (i.e. 7,8,11,12) using AutoHotkey script (the best thing would be to map them as POV but I am too "short" to figure that out).

I checked the pad device number and UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT key codes and came out with this:

```
SC14B::Send {3Joy11}  
SC14D::Send {3Joy12}  
SC148::Send {3Joy7}  
SC150::Send {3Joy8}
```

Unfortunatelly the only thing this script does is block use of arrows in notepad...
I also tried to assign the mapped arrows to D-pad using x360ce controller emulator but it still detects arrows as arrows, not as pad buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I love answering my own questions :)
So as it turns out from AutoHotkey documantation, it can only listen to Joy input but cannot generate it. For this purpouse there is another peace of software: PPJoy.